# IOS static library error "unrecognized selector sent to an instance"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, static-libraries

I have created the static library which compiles successfully,I have added .a file in the application where I want to use it. But getting the error `"unrecognised selector sent to an instance"`. But if I include the static library source in the application I am not getting any error. can someone help me in this issue.

Comment: The *unrecognized selector* is a runtime error, not a compiler one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the selector is implemented in a category and you’re missing the `-ObjC` linker flag? See the Apple [Technical QA1490](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/).

Comment: yes adding .h files and  -objc linker flag, but still getting runtime error. i am not using any categroies my source. please help me its very frushtrating for 3 days.

Comment: thanks i got resolved this issue using -Objc linker flag as well removing property accessor from weak to strong.